# Multiple queries in one final custom JSON

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I'm trying to create an api route using Node and Express and I must say I don't have much experience with it. Right know I have the following code:

```
app.get('/api/place/:id', (req, res) => {
var id = req.params.id;
var message_error = '{"status": "failed", "message": "Unable to fetch data"}';

db.query("SELECT `id`, `user`, `lat`, `lon`, `elevation`, `rating`, `rating_count`, `country`, `continent`, `locality` FROM `t_points` WHERE id = ?", [id], (err, res1) => {
    if(err) {
        res.json(message_error);
    } else {
        //Store the user id from the points table and use it to fetch user datas
        var userId = res1[0].user;
        if(userId != null) {
            db.query("SELECT `id`, `name` FROM `t_users` WHERE `id` = ?", [userId], (err, res2) => {
                if(err) {
                    res.json(message_error);
                } else {
                    //Final json structure
                    res.json({
                        id: res1[0].id,
                        lat: res1[0].lat,
                        lon: res1[0].lon,
                        elevation: res1[0].elevation,
                        rating: res1[0].rating,
                        rating_count: res1[0].rating_count,
                        user: {
                            id: res2[0].id,
                            name: res2[0].name
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        } else {
            res.json({
                id: res1[0].id,
                lat: res1[0].lat,
                lon: res1[0].lon,
                elevation: res1[0].elevation,
                rating: res1[0].rating,
                rating_count: res1[0].rating_count
            });
         }
      }    
  });
});
```

I'm hard-coding the json structure so if the userId in my table is null I don't print the user object in the json, otherwise I print it. But that's not a good idea, as I will also add more queries in the same route. Is there a simple way to create just one json at the end of all the queries and if some values are null not showing it?

Also, would it be better to use async and await functions to do it, instead of this way?

Thanks!

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use a join?

Comment: I was thinking of using that actually, that might get things simpler. But for the json I don't know if it's helpful? Also, I have 5 more queries in the route

Comment: Well, it means you're just manipulating an array, based on the result of a single query, rather than mashing together the results of 1+n queries.

Comment: Thanks, I will use that, but if the returned value is null I will have the "user" object anyway

Comment: I don't understand why that makes a difference.

Comment: Don't want to have "user": {"id": null, "name": null} to make it cleaner but i guess i could leave it that way

Comment: Sorry - you've lost me. Maybe see : [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

use util maybe better way to get result when querying data.

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const util = require('util');

// ? connection pool
let db = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 10,
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3306,
    user: 'root',
    password: 'secretpass',
    database: 'yourdatabasename'
});

// ? check connection
db.getConnection((err, connection) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('database connection failed');
    } else {
        console.log('database connection resolved');
        connection.release();
    }
});

// ? formatter query
function queryString(spName, ...queryParam) {
    return mysql.format(spName, queryParam);
}

// ? do query
let performQuery = util.promisify(db.query).bind(db)

module.exports = {
    performQuery,
    queryString
}
```

then use the function above like this :

```
app.get('/api/place/:id', async (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.id;
    const message_error = '{"status": "failed", "message": "Unable to fetch data"}';
    
    try {
      let prepareOne = queryString(SELECT `id`, `user`, `lat`, `lon`, `elevation`, `rating`, `rating_count`, `country`, `continent`, `locality` FROM `t_points` WHERE id = ?", id);
      let resultOne = await performQuery(prepareOne);
      let userId = resultOne[0].user;
      if (userId != null) {
          let prepareTwo = queryString("SELECT `id`, `name` FROM `t_users` WHERE `id` = ?", userId);
      let resultTwo = await performQuery(prepareTwo);
      res.json({
                 ...resultOne,
                 user: {
                         ...resultTwo
                        }
                 });
      }
    } catch (err) {
      res.send(message_error);
    }
```